# IMG SRC Not Changing To GIF in JS

Tags: javascript, animation, animated-gif, game-development

I am trying to create animations with JavaScript using a GIF and the `src` attribute for an `img`. So far, all of them work, except one. I have tried showing an alert when my if condition is met, and that seems to work. Also, all my other GIFs and PNGs are working. Here's my code:

```
else if (momentumX < 0) {
  if (document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src != "walkLeft.gif") {
    document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "walkLeft.gif";
  }
```

Here's my full game physics:

```
function onTimerTick() {
  if (moveY > 300) {
    momentumY = momentumY - 2;
    move(moveX, moveY);
  } else if (moveY < 300) {
    moveY = 300;
    momentumY = 0;
    move(moveX, moveY);
  }
  moveY = moveY + momentumY;
  move(moveX, moveY);
  if (moveY <= 300) {
    if (momentumX > 0) {
      right = true;
      momentumX -= 1;

    } else if (momentumX < 0) {
      if (document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src != "walkLeft.gif") {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "walkLeft.gif";
      }
      right = false;
      momentumX += 1;

    } else {
      if (right == true) {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "amaincharacter.png";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "maincharacterleft.png";
      }
    }
    moveX = moveX + momentumX;
  } else {
    moveX += momentumX / 3 + 1;
    document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "jumpmain.gif";
  }
  document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = momentumX;
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? We could use a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like it should work. Is there any way for you to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: One error, but it was just a missing semicolon and didn't affect the result.

Comment: Is the path correct?

Comment: Yes, my path is correct.

Comment: Is the element Id correct in your `img`?

Comment: Why have the check? If the `src` is already "walkLeft.gif", setting it to "walkLeft.gif" won't do anything. The problem is that some browsers, when you get the value of `src`, will report the full URL to the image, rather than just the file name, even if that's how you set it originally, so you end up having to do some substring gymnastics to get the correct value. In this case, it doesn't seem worth it.